# Populating a Table View in Swift with a JSON object

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I've looked at a number of other questions here but I am still relatively new to Swift and it's hard for me to place those answers into the context I have.

I have a database of events and I want to populate a tableview with said events. In my 'EventTableViewController' I have the following function:

```
func HTTPRequestListEvent() {
    let serverURL = NSURL(string: "http://localhost:8888/public_php/Cake/index.php/event/listevent")
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url:serverURL! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    //Create a task to send the post request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("HTTPRequestError1=\(error)")
            return
        }

        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject] {
                print("1")
                for (_, value) in json {
                    if let eventItem = value as? [String:AnyObject] {
                        if let eventName = eventItem["EventName"] as? String {
                            print(eventName)
                        }
                        if let eventLocation = eventItem["EventLocation"] as? String {
                            print(eventLocation)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("HTTPRequestError2=\(error)")
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

However, I cannot seem to get the JSON serialisation to work. It's not giving me an error, nor is it even printing out the '1'.

Also I don't want to be saying 'print(eventName)', but that is all I have so far. What I want to do is to do something like:

```
    cell.eventNameLabel.text = eventName
```

but I'm not sure how to get the cell details in this context.

Edit: My JSON has worked elsewhere, but for singular data - I've been able to log in and register users.

With postman, I get the following json data from my server:

[{"EventName":"Magnificent soirée","EventLocation":"Hot tub cinema","StartDate":"2017-12-01"},{"EventName":"Splendid party","EventLocation":"Gazeebo","StartDate":"2017-12-02"},{"EventName":"Magical event","EventLocation":"The end of a rainbow","StartDate":"2017-02-03"},{"EventName":"Slightly rubbish gathering","EventLocation":"Dungeon","StartDate":"2090-01-04"}]

Comment: Most likely your JSON isn't a dictionary.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your JSON?

Comment: @rmaddy what does that mean in layman's terms and what do I do with that information?

Comment: Your code is assuming the JSON's top level is a dictionary. But your JSON's top level is an array.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first. The reason your `print("1")` doesn't work is very simple. You are using an `if let` to unwrap the value and if the value is null, your codes inside the `if let` will be skipped. In you code simply add an `else` for your `if let` and do a print, and that will be printed out.

Now back to your question. The reason your `if let` doesn't work is the way you cast your JSON string. From the look at your JSON string, you have an array on top level. In your code, you are casting the result to `[String:AnyObject]` which is a Dictionary. So you get null as result because this casting failed. To fix your problem, here is a working sample of your code:

```
let str = "[{\"EventName\":\"Magnificent soirée\",\"EventLocation\":\"Hot tub cinema\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-12-01\"},{\"EventName\":\"Splendid party\",\"EventLocation\":\"Gazeebo\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-12-02\"},{\"EventName\":\"Magical event\",\"EventLocation\":\"The end of a rainbow\",\"StartDate\":\"2017-02-03\"},{\"EventName\":\"Slightly rubbish gathering\",\"EventLocation\":\"Dungeon\",\"StartDate\":\"2090-01-04\"}]"

do {
    let data = str.data(using: .utf8)
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [Dictionary<String, Any>] {
        print("1")
        for oneItemInJsonArray in json {
            if let eventName = oneItemInJsonArray["EventName"] as? String {
                print(eventName)
            }
            if let eventLocation = oneItemInJsonArray["EventLocation"] as? String {
                print(eventLocation)
            }
        }
    }else{
        print("fail")
    }
}
catch {
    print("HTTPRequestError2=\(error)")
}
```